# Linear Regression and Generating Data =+

Tags: python, arrays, olsmultiplelinearregression

I have been given a problem in Jupiter notebooks to code using python. This problem is about linear regression. It's as follows:

**1: Linear Regression**
In this notebook we will generate data from a linear function:  =+  and then solve for  ̂   using OLS (ordinary least squares) and gradient descent.

Question 1.1 : Generate data: =+
Here we assume ≈(,)=+ where  is linear in  with additive noise 
Your function should have the following properties:

output y as an np.array with shape (M,1)
generate_linear_y should work for any arbitrary x, b, and eps, as long as they are the appropriate dimensions
do not use for-loops to calculate each y[i] separately, as this will be very slow for large M and N. Instead, you should leverage numpy linear algebra.

---

They expect us to write code as follows:

```
def generate_linear_y(X,b):
""" Write a function that generates m data points from inputs X and b

Parameters
----------
X :   numpy.ndarray
      x.shape must be (M,N)
      Each row of `X` is a single data point of dimension N
      Therefore `X` represents M data points

b :   numpy.ndarray
      b.shape must be (N,1)
      Each element of `b` is a value of beta such that b=[[b1][b2]...[bN]]


Returns
-------
y :   numpy.ndarray
      y.shape = (M,1)
      y[i] = X[i]b
"""
```

---

Can someone please assist me because I am thoroughly confused! I didn't even realize the things I am doing required array coding in python, which I always struggle with! Please help!

Comment: If I were you, SO is not my place to go. I will start reading Linear Model with Numpy and from there this problem becomes small see https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~frossard/post/linear_regression/ among other tutorials on LM with numpy

Comment: @Prayson W. Daniel Thank you, I will check it out. SO was my last resort seeing as even my teachers weren't able to help me.

Comment: That was a really helpful link, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a direct matrix multiplication to me. In NumPy, this is implemented using the [matrix multiplication operator `@`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-65) (aka [`np.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html)).

To generate random noise, you can use the functions from [`numpy.random`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html), most likely [`random_sample`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random_sample.html) or [`standard_normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.standard_normal.html). If you want to do it the most-correct way, you can create a random number generator with [`default_rng`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.default_rng), then use, for instance, `rng.standard_normal`.

Comment: can you please show me an example of the code, because I have never even heard of those functions.

Comment: omg I know this is TMI but I'm about to cry, I feel so lost and confused and I've never done anything like this. I desperately need help, so I turned to stack overflow which im new to.

Comment: @ah123412312 It sounds like you want to return either `X @ b` or that plus some noise. To get standard-normally-distributed noise of the same shape as your output, you could save that in a variable (`y1`), and use `np.random.standard_normal(y1.shape)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working out! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @ah123412312 If my solution worked, please accept my answer.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize I was supposed to do that, I did it though and thanks!